# I need to call second Activity by pressing in TextView (Eclipse)

Tags: android, eclipse

I need to start a new activity by clicking on a `TextView`.
My code:

```
txtFirst = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
txtFirst.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (indTxt == 3) {
            Intent intent = new Intent (this, ActSecond.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
});
```

I pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>, but Eclipse displays the following error:

[image: screenshot]

On this line:

```
Intent intent = new Intent (this, ActSecond.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

after:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

Then all is good...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass Current Activity or Application Context instead of any View Context as first parameter to Intent Constructor (Currently by using `this` you are trying to passing View Context to Intent  Constructor) as :

```
Intent intent = new Intent (Current_Activity.this, ActSecond.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

instead of

```
Intent intent = new Intent (this, ActSecond.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 3):

Here `this` is not referring to your class but to the OnClickListener, try:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ActFirst.this, ActSecond.class);
```

(Assuming that `ActFirst` is your class' name.)

---

Also I don't know if you have done this yet but: you need to set a TextView to be `clickable` before the OnClickListener will work.

Either in the XML with:

```
android:clickable="true"
```

or Java:

```
txtFirst.setClickable(true);
```